Roth conversion as Canadian Resident
I am soon planning to move to Canada and take up a job in Canada for next 2-3 years. During my US journey of 10+ years, I have funded my 401k and Traditional IRA.
I would like to know can I do Roth Conversion and also rollover from 401k after moving to Canada and if I can, how and where I need to pay those tax?
FYI, I am not US-citizen or LPR.

Can you do Roth conversion and rollover before you move? That should be a lot easier. After you move to Canada, it's probably an edge case that would require the help of an accountant/tax attorney with relevant knowledge.
